# Pass JSON object as argument in JNI to CPP and retrieve JSON Objects's data in CPP

Tags: c++, json, java-native-interface

Need to input data from a java program using class object, convert it to json object and pass to c++ through JNI.
In C++,
have to retrieve the data from the object and store it in a file.

I dont know how to send and retrieve a json object's data.
Help me out with some simple code snippets!!

```
class sample
{  

    public native void callCPP(JSONObject jo);    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {  
        int val = 7;  
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject;  
        jo.put("val",val);

        sample s = new sample();
        s.callCPP(jo);  
    }  
}
```

and the vice versa too(sending data from cpp to java as JSONObject.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works.  Questions of the form _"I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code"_ are considered off-topic.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157)

Comment: The problem is the solution: JSON is a data interchange format! Simply flatten your data structure to a JSON string, pass that across the JNI boundary, and parse it on the other side.

Comment: That is what exactly i shouldnt do!!. i must not pass as s string, i have to pass as a object, retreive data from that and store it.. @Botje

Comment: Then I do not understand your question. Please add code (real code, preferrably, but pseudocode will do).

Comment: Thats my problem, i dont know where to start. Tell me whether a json object can be passed as an argument to c++. @Botje.. Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as "a JSON object". You either have a string that contains JSON, or a Java object that *happens* to have "JSON" in its name. If you have the latter, you can pass it across the JNI boundary and use JNI and regular Java methods to interact with the object. Of course this is an order of magnitude more painful than simply presenting C++ with a JSON string (flattened from your "json object") and have it process it on its own.

Comment: Ive added a code snippet.. Im referring to that json object...  My need is access the val in CPP. @Botje

Comment: Is this an `org.json.JSONObject`? a `javax.json.JSONObject`? an `org.json.simple.JSONObject?` The answer is the same for all three: find out how you would access `val` from Java and port that to JNI. The pattern is always the same: `FindClass` to get at the class definition, `GetMethodID` to get the method ID you need , `Call{Type}Method` to call it.

Comment: can you explain this with a small code snippet please.. just print the val in c++. Thanks in advance.@Botje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you meant [`org.json.JSONObject`](http://stleary.github.io/JSON-java/org/json/JSONObject.html):

```
void Java_sample_callCPP(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobject arg) {
    // This code calls arg->getInt("val"), assuming it is a org.json.JSONObject
    jclass cls = env->FindClass("org/json/JSONObject"); // alternatively: env->GetObjectClass(arg);
    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getInt", "(Ljava/lang/String;)I"); // int getInt(java.lang.String key)
    jint val = env->CallIntMethod(arg, method, env->NewStringUTF("val"));
    std::cout << "val: " << val << std::endl;

    jmethodId method2 = env->GetMethodID(cls, "getString", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring strVal = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(arg, method2, env->NewStringUTF("strVal"));

    // Make a copy of the returned Java string. We need to release the pointer again, too.
    const jchar *ptr = env->GetStringUTFChars(strVal, nullptr);
    std::string strVal_copy(ptr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(strVal, ptr);
    std::cout << "strVal: " << strVal_copy << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,, But I Must Not use call back method.. Because i am having a long range of attributes.. i cant use a method for each variable everytime.. Moreover whats the use with JSONObject here?

Comment: Which of these lines of code uses a "call back method" according to you? And why is it a problem to use JNI methods to get at the properties? This is exactly what you asked! If you do not want this, you need to serialize your objects at the java side and deserialize on the C++ side. Then you can use native C++ methods to inspect your C++ object.

Comment: Sorry If Im Bugging.. Please tell me how to do it!

Comment: How to do what? You asked how to use JNI to inspect a Java object, I answered.  There is **no other way** to access a Java object from C++.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.. Youve been huge help!.. The method you mentioned works fine for me!! thanks again.. But can you please tell me how to retrieve a String in that pleasee..

Comment: Updated my answer. See also [the JNI cookbook example](http://jnicookbook.owsiak.org/recipe-No-009/)

Comment: If this solves your problem, please mark the question as accepted.

Comment: Hey Botje, can i ask you another favour,. can you show me how to do the exact opposite of this, like saving class's objects in JSONObject from c++ and returning it to Java. Please

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Furthermore, this is a different question, albeit closely related to [this JNI cookbook sample that passes a `map<int, int>` to Java](https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo048).

Comment: actually ive tried using map, vector etc,, but it always says "%1 is not a valid win32 application", so now im forced to work on this. Please help me, i have a group of data in a file, have to retrive it and pass as JSONObject to java(or any similar method) like you  used getInt , and print it there. Please help me. @Botje

Comment: Post a new question and **show your work**. The sample I linked shows how to construct a HashMap and fill it with values. Read through it and adapt it to `org.json.JSONObject`.

Comment: While you are waiting, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking-rate-limited  and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so people do not have to extract vital details from you in the comments on your next question.